# Gráfico Pie Chart do Google fica desformatado ao ser chamado por função Javascript

Tags: javascript, google-charts, css-display

Olá, pessoal. 
Estou tendo problema ao tornar um gráfico que está com "display:none" em "display: block" através do Javascript. O problema é que quando eu torno o gráfico visível ele fica menor do que o esperado.

O gráfico está ficando com esta resolução

[image: O gráfico está ficando com esta resolução]

Quando deveria ficar com esta resolução

[image: Quando deveria ficar com esta resolução]

Segue abaixo como está o código do gráfico em questão

**Código html**

```
<div id="relat_sit_table" style="display:none;">
<div class='tab_title'>Situação UC Sem Medidor <?php echo "($mees/$anoo)"; ?></div><br/>
<div id='table_div_estilo2'><br/>
<div id='table_div3'></div></div><br/>
</div>
<div id="relat_sit_det2" style="display:none"><p class="relat_sit_det2"> Veja comparação entre os últimos meses <a href="#" name="relat_sit2" onClick="optionCheck4()">aqui</a></p></div>
```

**Javascript**

```
function optionCheck1(){
      document.getElementById("columnchart_material_2").style.display ="none";
      document.getElementById("piechart").style.display ="block";    
      document.getElementById("relat_class_det1").style.display ="none";
      document.getElementById("relat_class_det2").style.display ="block";
            }
```

Comment: O gráfico todo ou só a pizza?

Comment: Só a pizza.....

Comment: Faz o seguinte: em vez de inciar ele com display: none, coloque invisível e com position: absolute, assim: `style="visibility: hidden; position: absolute;"`... depois com o JS vc altera com `ELEMENTO.style.visibility = "visible"` e `ELEMENTO.style.position = "relative"`

Comment: Perfeito, amigo! Funcionou, obrigado!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Isso se dá porque a API pode não dimensionar corretamente o gráfico em `div` oculta, obtendo valores incorretos das dimensões do contêiner.

Uma forma de contornar isso é tirando a visibilidade da `div` (diferente de ocultar) com a propriedade `visibility: hidden` e `position: absolute` para que não fique o espaço vazio da `div` invisível.

Ao chamar a função para mostrá-la, altere a `visibility` para `visible` e a `position` para `relative`.

Na `div` do gráfico coloque o `style`:

```
style="visibility: hidden; position: absolute;"
```

E altere na função com:

```
document.getElementById("ID_DA_DIV").style.position = "relative";
document.getElementById("ID_DA_DIV").style.visibility = "visible";
```